# Plugin to process change log for a rendered html form

Tags: javascript, jquery

today I got an assignment from my school and I am bit confused about it, what this assignment ask me to do, here I paste the same

Assignment:
Design and code a jQuery Plugin to process change log for a rendered html form.

1) You need to store the initial values set to the form inputs.

2) On submit of form, you need to calculate the changes made to the form values.

3) Add the change log object as "changelog" parameter to the form.

can anyone figure out what this assignment ask to do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Smamatti thanks for the edit :)

Comment: People please help me I need to submit this on this Monday :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store a default configuration (initial values). A simple variable will do in the beginning, I guess.
2. Write a function to compare the submitted values to the default configuration.
3. Create the obejct and append it to the DOM
4. Design this as part of a jQuery plugin.

Take a look at:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)
- Value comparison (i.e Strings/numbers)
- [DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) (i.e. jQuery's function like append. to add the object)

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

You need a form with a script reference to the jquery plugin.
You can write the code first in plain JS/HTML and put it together in the plugin afterwards.
Something like this for starters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var default = "my value";

/* ... */

function check_values() {
    /* select and check input */
    /* ... */
    /* append object within the form ? */
}
</script>


<form ... onsubmit="check_values();">

    /* inputs etc. ... */

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed some similar type of plugin. just lookout at:
https://github.com/mukeshyadav/changelog-form